# Creating short url for multiple controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter

For my current project in codeignitor I needed to make user profile like this

```
http://domain.com/userid
```

Then I tried to add this in router.php

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'profile/user/$1';
```

Which is working fine. Now I want to make another URL for language like this

```
http://domain.com/es
http://domain.com/fr
```

As for both url uri segments are first, when I type

```
 http://domain.com/es
```

I see the page of

```
 http://domain.com/userid
```

I am using .htaccess file for removing index.php in codeignitor. Is there any help how can I achive this task in making shot url for multiple controller. Either with .htaccess or router.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the routes system works from the top down, if you have multiple rules that can match a url, it picks the first one.  So you could do:

```
$route['(es|fr|en)'] = 'language/$1';
$route['(:any)'] = 'profile/user/$1';
```

If the first rule matches, it runs, otherwise it tests the profile rule.
You will definitely continue running into issues though with that profile rule, and it would be easier if you did something like:

```
$route['users/(:any)'] = 'profile/user/$1';
```

That way it would be more clear what the url is doing, and it will help you for when you are writing rules in the future.

Comment: Thanks mazzz to answer. It's just staring of my project so I am not that far to change $route['users/(:any)'] = 'profile/user/$1'; but I want url without user in domin.com/user/id, do you think I should do that by .htaccess or will give same result?

Comment: It would give the same result, I have the same issue as you.  I always obsess on how to make the urls prettier, but it doesn't really matter, and in the end, using `users/(:any)` will make your life a lot easier, and it will make maintaining the code easier as well.